# Javascript - API names in switch

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api

I have a node.js restful server that receives API calls

```
let method = request.query.method;
```

I setup a list of available APIs

```
enum apis {
    api_name_1,
    api_name_2
}
```

I want to switch the method I got into the available APIs

```
switch (method) {
   case apis.api_name_1:
      response.send("You asked for api 1");
      break;
   case apis.api_name_2:
      response.send("You asked for api 2");
      break;
   default:
      response.send("This method is not supported: " + method);
      break;
}
```

When calling the API like this: api/process?method=api_name_2 , node.js receives is as "api_name_2" (as string) while apis.api_name_2 is equivalent to 1 (enum). How can I convert the name of the api into a "readable" api code for node.js?

Thanks

Comment: Enums are not native to JS and you didn't mention what you are using for them. Different implementations have different APIs. Also I disagree with your need or use of them for this, why not an object with key values? (Though I also disagree with your idea of matching by the method query instead of using a more flexible and powerful URL based router as is standard to do)

Comment: I'm still new to this, if you can direct me to read more about "using a more flexible and powerful URL based router" I'd appreciate it. bear in mind that method is not the only parameter I will need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve by the enum section. Also while you are comparing you can simply compare the strings in switch cases

Here is the code

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()


app.get('/api/process', function(req, res) {
    let method = req.query.method;
    console.log(method)


    switch (method) {
        case 'apis.api_name_1':
            res.send("You asked for api 1");
            break;
        case 'apis.api_name_2':
            res.send("You asked for api 2");
            break;
        default:
            res.send("This method is not supported: " + method);
            break;
    }
})

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Magic begins on port 3000!')
})
```

**EDITED CODE**
I have updated to code below, since enums are not native to JS as of now and `enum` is a reserved word in JS, I have replaced the enum implementation of yours with a object.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

var apiEnum = {
    api_name_1: 'apis.api_name_1',
    api_name_2: 'apis.api_name_2'
};
app.get('/api/process', function(req, res) {
    let method = req.query.method;
    console.log(method)


    switch (method) {
        case apiEnum.api_name_1:
            res.send("You asked for api 1");
            break;
        case apiEnum.api_name_2:
            res.send("You asked for api 2");
            break;
        default:
            res.send("This method is not supported: " + method);
            break;
    }
})

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Magic begins on port 3000!')
})
```

Now if you hit `http://localhost:3000/api/process?method=apis.api_name_2`, you will get the desired result

Comment: Your solution works ofcourse but I thought of making a list of available APIs for other uses and use this list in the switch as well

Comment: @Amos I have updated the code. Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property access operator `[]` to get the value from the string as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39551568/convert-javascript-enum-key-string-to-value): `code = apis[method];`.

Comment: It works but in the ts file I get a red line saying apis.api_name_1 can't work as string (code = apis[method] returns string). In debug, both values are 0 as expected and it works

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380845/how-to-convert-string-to-enum-in-typescript) may provide more insight.

Comment: sorry for being slow here but again I'm missing something. I did the following: let methodCode:apis = apis[method]; but I get Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'apis' even though this is equivalent to the answer he got